# Get files into git repo without full clone

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

we are running some tools doing anonymization of production data which is then used for testing. I'd like to commit this anonymized data (basically .csv files) into the projects git repo but I don't want to have all the sourcecode from the git repo on the server performing this anonymization.

Is there a way to just checkout a small subfolder from git or "inject" this .csv files directly into the git repo? Or would it maybe be better to include a small script into the git ci/cd which downloads the newest test data from some url?

Thank you :)